# How to add a counter to the id attribute of <input>. I want to activate links every time I check a check box

Tags: html

How to add counter to incerement the agreeCheckbox id in the input tag? I am using django template to show the links only when the checkbox is checked.

```
{% for catalog in object_list %} 

<div class="container"> 




        <tbody>
            <tr>


    enter code here

        <td>
        <form>
         **<p><input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox" onchange="toggleLink(this);"></p>**
                </form>
                </td>
                <td>{{ catalog.DatasetName }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.Type }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.Classification }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.OriginalSource }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.OriginalOwner }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.YearOfOrigin }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="card-footer text-center text-muted"> 
    <a href="{% url 'catalog_edit' catalog.pk %}" id="agreeLink1" style="display:none;">Update</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'catalog_delete' catalog.pk %}" id="agreeLink2" style="display:none;">Delete</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'export_to_xml' %}" id="agreeLink3" style="display:none;">Export to XML</a>
</div> 

{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The for loop iterates over the checboxes and displays the links only when each of the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'forloop.counter' ->

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox{{ forloop.counter }}" [..]
```

[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: i added the {{ loop.index }} but its not working. Is there a different way to implement this.

Comment: Update and Delete links are for each row in the table. I want the links of each row to be activated when I click the checkbox for that particular row. Does anyone know how to do it? I added the {{forloop.counter}} and now it is generating a new id but all the ids are still linked to the links of the first row. each row has its own links and those links need to be activated when I click the checkbox for that row.

Comment: sorry, i've mistaken your template code for twig, since the syntax is similar. i've updated my answer with the django thing :)

Comment: you asked for a counter, which i provided. if this question is answered, please accept the answer, if not, tell us what error it is producing. for the second question in your comment, please create another question for this.

Comment: ok creating a counter worked so far. Thanks for the suggestion. I will create a new question for the second question.

Comment: if the answer is correct and solved your problem, would you please be so kind and accept it? :)

Comment: new to stack overflow